# HTTP Service Streaming (XMLHttpRequest to long-lived server) in chrome: high jitter

Tags: google-chrome, xmlhttprequest, streaming

I'm trying to implement the [service streaming pattern](http://ajaxpatterns.org/HTTP_Streaming) with Chrome's XMLHttpRequest object as a client in order to display an animation along a path determined by the server in real time.  As noted at " [Google Chrome and Streaming HTTP connections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237553/google-chrome-and-streaming-http-connections)" I've ensured a large chunk of data is sent on initial connection, and I am able to receive data from the server line by line.  However, while the server is sending data periodically (every 300ms +- about 20ms) I'm getting an unacceptably large amount of jitter in chrome (up to +200ms for occasional lines).  The server is running on localhost, so this is not network lag.  Any ideas what might be causing it, or how I can fix it (short of buffering more of the animation than I currently am, which would be unacceptable as this is an interactive application)?